# Why does .getstring-Method produces an empty cell at the bottom of the table?

Tags: asp-classic, ado, getstring

My -layout is not as expected:
Why does .getstring create a single cell at the end of the table?
Is this a bug?
Can you fix this via getrow and join?

Thanks for your tips

[Getstring-Example@ http://www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_display5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known... well, *annoyance*. (Otherwise known as a bug that will never get fixed.) You either have to trim off the extra delimiters using `Left()`, or you have to use something other than `.GetString`. `.GetRows` is probably the most useful, but note that you can't use `Join` with it: the latter requires a one-dimensional array, while `GetRows` always returns a two-dimensional array, even if the recordset only returned one column and/or row.

Comment: Thank you Martha.It's funny that you can't find any hints about that behaviour. Even Db-Tutorials don't fix that problem. E.g. W3school only emphazise the speed of the getstring-Method

Comment: What do you think about this modification. Is this practicable:

Comment: pseudo-code: rs.Open "SELECT '<tr><td>' + Companyname + '</td><td>' + Contactname + "</td></tr>' FROM Customers", conn
str=rs.GetString(,,,chr$(13),"") - - for just getting the HTML-result. The empty row should be only appear in html not in a real tr/td-tag

Comment: That can work, though I probably wouldn't even worry about putting line breaks in the html. (Or if I did want the source code to look pretty, I'd use `vbCrLf` rather than `chr(13)`.)